# Link not opening properly after hiding file extension using htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I have used ht-access to hide `.php` file extension. Inside `.htaccess` file my code is :

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>
```

It's hiding `.php` file extension well. **But problem is that**, link inside `href` attribute is not opening properly.

I have two files:

> `public_html/afiliate/product_details.php`
>
> `public_html/afiliate/afiliate_login.php`

Inside *`product_details.php`* I have given link of *`afiliate_login.php`*  like this

```
<a href="afiliate_login.php" target="_blank">Log in</a>
```

Clicking **Log in** I should go to a page like

> `example.com/afiliate/afiliate_login/`

But it takes me to

> `example.com/afiliate/product_details/afiliate_login/`

And hence a 404 error

Again notice that, if i manually type this URL

> `example.com/afiliate/afiliate_login/`

that's OK, it goes to the page as expected.

Now how I can make links work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously the browser considered `product_details.php` as a file. but now its a folder,  because its `product_details/`

one option available here is to update the link's like this

```
<a href="../afiliate_login.php" target="_blank">Log in</a>
```

but its always suggested like the link below

```
<a href="/afiliate_login" target="_blank">Log in</a>
```

Comment: Its working, but when  .php is hidden , image and .js files are not loading

Comment: may be there is a slash added to the image and js files.

Answer (score 2):

After this code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```

put the below code

```
RewriteRule afiliate_login$   afiliate_login.php [L]
```

basically means that any request that comes to `afiliate_login` will show the data from `afiliate_login.php`

You got that problem because in your anchor tag you are using relative url. Since your url look like this without the file extension like, `example.com/afiliate/afiliate_login/` ,  `affiliate_login/` will be also considered as a directory and the html thinks that the anchor tag is in `affiliate_login/` but it in reality it does not exists there so you get 404 error.

Comment: check if the file `afiliate_login.php` actually exists and what is the path where it is stored and i can see that you are using `.php` extension for that file. What is the path where the afiliate_login.php is actually stored.